# Make atom plugin always toggled

Tags: plugins, atom-editor

i create some simple plugin for changing icons, only with styles file and without scripts. How to make the plugin always activated after install? Because at this moment  i have to toggle my plugin in menu after every atom reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
I should just delete "activationCommand" field from package.json.